# Open TWA app instead of the web app when user clicks the push notification

Tags: javascript, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, twa

Current behaviour: When the user clicks the push notification the web app open, even if the TWA app is installed in the android phone.

Expected behaviour: When the user clicks the push notification I want to open the TWA (Trusted web activity) app.

I am using Firebase for push notification

I just using google's sample repo (https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa) as my base and overwriting it.

the URL I am trying to open when the user clicks the notification is similar to https://dev.example.com/

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LauncherActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/assetStatements" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="cros_web_alternative"
            android:value="@string/crosLaunchUrl" />

        <activity android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity"
            android:label="@string/appName">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DEFAULT_URL"
                android:value="@string/launchUrl" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.STATUS_BAR_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.NAVIGATION_BAR_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/navigationColor" />

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_IMAGE_DRAWABLE"
                android:resource="@drawable/splash"/>

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_SCREEN_BACKGROUND_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/backgroundColor"/>

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.SPLASH_SCREEN_FADE_OUT_DURATION"
                android:value="@integer/splashScreenFadeOutDuration"/>

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY"
                android:value="@string/providerAuthority"/>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts" android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="@string/hostName"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/providerAuthority"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>

        <service
             android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.TrustedWebActivityService"
             android:enabled="@bool/enableNotification"
             android:exported="@bool/enableNotification">

             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.TRUSTED_WEB_ACTIVITY_SERVICE"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
             </intent-filter>
         </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you add the AndroidManifest.xml to the issue and also more details on the URL that is being opened when the user clicks on the push notification?

Comment: @andreban update the question with the details you asked for.

Comment: All looks right in the manifest. Would you be able to share the APK (or the link to the store if it has been uploaded to Play?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug that was introduced in Chrome 80.

Check this chromium bug out for more details:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1052288

Comment: Thanks to this comment, we have reached the issue!
Thank you!It may be better to wait for the next Chrome version because it seems to be fixed!

Comment: This should be fixed in Chrome 81. It may be worth testing agains Chrome Beta or Chrome Dev to confirm it works for you until its stable

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry.

I happened to do that too. Probably from Chrom80.

So delete the comment.

Comment: I'm sorry.

I happened to do that too. Probably from Chrom80.